# Python sample and remove item from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random

Is there a single command to randomly sample an item for a list and remove it?
let say the command named cmd, I want something like that?

```
l = [1,2,4,6]
r = cmd(l)
r = 4
l = [1,2,6]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `random.randint` to get a random index and use `pop` to get the element with that index from the list

```
>>> import random
>>> l = [1,2,4,6]
>>> idx = random.randint(0, len(l)-1)
>>> r = l.pop(idx)
>>> r
4
>>> l
[1, 2, 6]
```

Comment: Almost... `randint()` *includes* the end number so if `len(l)` is chosen - it'll be an invalid index and cause an `IndexError` on the pop attempt... you want `random.randrange(len(l))`

Comment: ha... thanks for the explanation.. Updated the answer

Comment: I suppose you can do that... but `randint` calls `randrange(a, b+1)` so you might as well just call `randrange` directly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: `l.pop(random.randint(0, len(l)))`

p.s. sorry, forgot about random

Answer (score 0):

Shuffle using `random.shuffle` and then `pop` from list:

```
import random

lst = [1, 2, 4, 6]
random.shuffle(lst)
r = lst.pop()

print(r)    # 4
print(lst)  # [1, 2, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `choice` from the module `random` and use `remove` to remove the item from list.

```
>>> from random import choice as get
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,6]
>>> r = get(l)
>>> r
3
>>> l.remove(r)
>>> l
[1, 2, 4, 6]
```

In short:

```
from random import choice as get
l = [1,2,3,4,6]
r = get(l)
l.remove(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to use [`shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) to randomise the elements position in the list and then use `pop()` as and when required.

```
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> shuffle(l)
>>> l.pop()
```

#driver values :

```
IN : l = [1,2,4,6]
OUT : 4
```

---

From PyDocs :

> random.shuffle(x[, random])
>
> ```
> Shuffle the sequence x in place.
> ```